# startLeScan is depecrated in API21

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am developing an android application that use the Bluetooth low energy. i used the class `BluetoothAdapter` but now in the API-21 the class is `BluetoothLeScanner` my old code was implementing the interface BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback what interface must i implement now ? or is there another solution that i can do ?
the two methods `stopLeScan` and `startLeScan` are deprecated that's why i want to use the class `BluetoothLeScanner` it has the methods start and stop instead.

this is the code of my class:

```
public class BleDevicesScanner implements Runnable, BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback {
    private static final String TAG = BleDevicesScanner.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final long DEFAULT_SCAN_PERIOD = 500L;
    public static final long PERIOD_SCAN_ONCE = -1;

    private final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private final Handler mainThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    private final LeScansPoster leScansPoster;

    private long scanPeriod = DEFAULT_SCAN_PERIOD;
    private Thread scanThread;
    private volatile boolean isScanning = false;

    public BleDevicesScanner(BluetoothAdapter adapter, BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback callback) {
        if (adapter == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Adapter should not be null");

        bluetoothAdapter = adapter;

        leScansPoster = new LeScansPoster(callback);
    }

    public synchronized void setScanPeriod(long scanPeriod) {
        this.scanPeriod = scanPeriod < 0 ? PERIOD_SCAN_ONCE : scanPeriod;
    }

    public boolean isScanning() {
        return scanThread != null && scanThread.isAlive();
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if (isScanning())
            return;

        if (scanThread != null) {
            scanThread.interrupt();
        }
        scanThread = new Thread(this);
        scanThread.setName(TAG);
        scanThread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        isScanning = false;
        if (scanThread != null) {
            scanThread.interrupt();
            scanThread = null;
        }
        bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            isScanning = true;
            do {
                synchronized (this) {
                    bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(this);
                }

                if (scanPeriod > 0)
                    Thread.sleep(scanPeriod);

                synchronized (this) {
                    bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
                }
            } while (isScanning && scanPeriod > 0);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        } finally {
            synchronized (this) {
                bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        synchronized (leScansPoster) {
            leScansPoster.set(device, rssi, scanRecord);
            mainThreadHandler.post(leScansPoster);
        }
    }

    private static class LeScansPoster implements Runnable {
        private final BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback;

        private BluetoothDevice device;
        private int rssi;
        private byte[] scanRecord;

        private LeScansPoster(BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback) {
            this.leScanCallback = leScanCallback;
        }

        public void set(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            this.device = device;
            this.rssi = rssi;
            this.scanRecord = scanRecord;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            leScanCallback.onLeScan(device, rssi, scanRecord);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Android documenation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startLeScan(android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback)) describes to use the new `BluetoothAdapter` `startScan()` method:

```
public void startScan (List<ScanFilter> filters, ScanSettings settings, ScanCallback callback)
```

You could create a `BleDevicesScannerV21` class for API level 21 and above which uses `ScanCallback` instead of `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback`.

Comment: i extended from `ScanCallback` but how can i use it ??
i can't instanciate it cuz it's an abstract class and the method `startScan` dosen't have the same signature with `startlescan`